# There is time comes of 'last chance' too

Tags: prepositions, coordination

"Life gives so many chances, do not misuse them because there is time comes of 'last chance' too"

In this part usage of "of" is ok?

Comment: This is not an idiomatic English sentence, with or without *of*. Do you mean something like "The time of [your] last chance will [eventually] come, too"?

Comment: What StoneyB said. @arm - you should edit your text to provide *at least a complete sentence*, and explain exactly what you want it to mean.

Comment: Yes that's exactly I mean what StoneyB says. I have updated the whole sentence.

Answer (score 4):

We would not say that this way.

Addressing your specific question: we do not split the *of* phrase from the noun it modifies by putting another constituent between them, as you have put *comes* between *time* and *of last chance*.

But there are other problems here:

1. *There is time comes* is ungrammatical—you have two subjects and two verbs in one clause. You must either eliminate one pair or make it a subordinate construction

   > A time comes... *or*
   >   There is a time which comes...
2. *Time of last chance* is not idiomatic English. We don't use *time* here because *time* in this sense (meaning approximately  “occasion”) is semantically “built in” to the phrase *last chance*. Your *last chance* to do something is your *final opportunity* to do it, the last occasion on which you will be permitted to do it.

One way to say this is:

> Life gives you many chances; do not misuse them, because the last chance always comes, too.

It would be even better if you fortified the parallelism:

> Life gives you many chances; do not misuse them, because in the end life will give you the last chance, too.